# Get the month and year from today's date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the month and year for today's date.

```
Sub automation()

Dim wsheet As Worksheet
Dim month As Integer
Dim year As Integer

Set wsheet = Application.Workbooks("try").Worksheets("try")

month = Application.WorksheetFunction.month(Date)

year = Application.WorksheetFunction.year(Date)

End Sub
```

My expected output is 5 for month and 2017 for year if today's date is 15/5/2017.

Answer (score 6):

You may have some problem because you've shadowed some existing functions `Month` and `Year` with your variable names `month` and `year`. So, use different variable names:

```
Dim m As Integer
Dim y As Integer
```

And then either:

```
m = DatePart("m", Date)
y = DatePart("yyyy", Date)
```

Or:

```
m = month(Date)
y = year(Date)
```

In my Excel 2010 (not tested in 2013) while `Month` is a worksheet function, it's not exposed to VBA for some reason. If you want to use the `WorksheetFunction` instance of these, you *can* technically do it using the `Application.Evaluate` method, like so:

```
m = Evaluate("MONTH(""" & Date & """)")
y = Evaluate("YEAR(""" & Date & """)")
```

The built-in `VBA.DateTime.Month` and `VBA.DateTime.Year` functions, however, are available and that is what would be used in the second example above.

[image]

If you *must* for some reason retain the `month` and `year` variable names, then you need to fully qualify the function call to avoid error:

```
month = VBA.DateTime.Month(Date)
year = VBA.DateTime.Year(Date)
```

Comment: The *fully* qualified name would actually be `VBA.DateTime.Month` ;-)

Comment: Why do you guys have to be smarter than me O_o

Answer (score 5):

Change in your code like this:

```
Sub CurrentDate()

    Dim currentMonth As Long
    Dim currentYear As Long

    currentMonth = Month(Date)
    currentYear = Year(Date)

    Debug.Print currentMonth; currentYear

End Sub
```

`Month` and `Year` are functions of the `VBA.DateTime`, do not use them for variable names.

In general, `Application.WorksheetFunction` does not have a function, related to current date, in contrast to `VBA.DateTime.Month` or `VBA.DateTime.Year` (or at least I did not find) any in the Excel Library.

Comment: `Month` and `Year` are functions in the `VBA.DateTime` module, not reserved ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
dim this as date
this = Format(Date(), "yyyy") 
this = Format(Date(), "mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering late but I wanted to reference the VBA documentation from microsoft's own page.

To get Month from date:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function

Sample snippet:

```
Dim MyDate, MyMonth
MyDate = #February 12, 1969#    ' Assign a date.
MyMonth = Month(MyDate)    ' MyMonth contains 2.
```

To get Year from date:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function

Sample snippet:

```
Dim MyDate, MyYear
MyDate = #February 12, 1969#    ' Assign a date.
MyYear = Year(MyDate)    ' MyYear contains 1969.
```

Answer (score 0):

I like these answers, but I needed one that would contain *both* the month and year in the format (my use case is as an accountant). This was my solution:

```
Dim today As Date
today = Date ' Get the current date

Dim period As String
period = Format(today, "MM/YYYY") ' Convert the date to MM/YYYY
```